# Excel vba Split string

Tags: excel, vba, string, split

```
`FileContent = "|Value|Z^|^X^|^Y^|^

|Value|Z^|^X1

^|^Y1^|^|Value|Z^|^X2

^|^Y2^|^"`
```

`someArray() = Split(FileContent, "|Value|")`

is not splitting the lengthy string into arrays, returns an empty result.

```
someArray(0) = |Value|Z^|^X^|^Y^|^
someArray(1) = |Value|Z^|^X1^|^Y1^|^
someArray(2) = |Value|Z^|^X2^|^Y2^|^"
```

Comment: Unable to reproduce: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AJrsn.png

Comment: Works for me too.  Is that last block the "expected" outcome?  "|Value|" will not appear there.

Comment: what if there is new line(vblf) in between? @BigBen

Comment: yes  "|Value|" is needed. but i could add it after the split right?. @TimWilliams

Comment: Yes you can add it back.  If your data has new lines you can replace those before the Split

Answer (score 0):

The issue occurred due to new line in between the string. Removed the new line using

```
FileContent = Replace(FileContent, vbLf, "")

FileContent = Replace(FileContent, vbCrLf, "")

FileContent = Replace(FileContent, vbCr, "")
```